# Using SQL to TRIM and find duplicates not working

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, trim

I have to search and remove duplicates from a table of airport codes.  the duplicates are not exact duplicates.  One record may be 'standard' and the other record may have a leading "K".

Example of airport records that represent the same airport (duplicates for our purposes):

```
column: identity
N57
KN57
```

I thought I could accomplish this by stripping the leading "K" from all records and comparing this to the non-stripped records by using this SQL:

```
SELECT identity
FROM tbl_airports
WHERE identity IN (SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'K' FROM identity) FROM tbl_airports)
```

My goal is to return the version without the leading "K", so I can then turn the SQL into a delete statement to remove the duplicate records.

However, the SQL above does not seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete records with the leading `k`, you can do something like this:

```
delete a
    from tbl_airports a
    where a.identity like 'K%' and
          exists (select 1 from tbl_airports a2 where 'K' + a2.identity = a.identity);
```

This uses SQL Server syntax, but something similar will work in most databases.

With "phpadmin" in the tags, this is probably MySQL.  In that database, you would do this with a `join`:

```
delete a join
       (select 'K' + a2.identity as identity
        from tbl_airports
        where a2.identity not like 'K%'
       ) ak
       on a.identity = ak.identity
    where a.identity like 'K%';
```

EDIT:

The `select` version of the query is:

```
select a.*
from a join
     (select 'K' + a2.identity as identity
      from tbl_airports
      where a2.identity not like 'K%'
     ) ak
     on a.identity = ak.identity
 where a.identity like 'K%';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these don't seem to be working.  I tried them as a select statement first and they returned results that do not have matches with K### and ###    MySQL is the DB.

Comment: Which version do you want removed?  These queries remove the version that starts with `K`.

Comment: That would be fine.  Can you create a query first to test that it will return all items that start with a K and have a "duplicate" without a K?  I need that to see that it works before deleting.  Thanks!